# Query using FMDB not returning result

Tags: sqlite, fmdb

I am trying to get the next highest PK in an SQLite database that was not originally set up with auto increment and already has hundreds of records.  So I made the below method which seems like it should work, but I am not able to get any results from this.  I have several other methods that get data from the database that work and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and I'm going cross-eyed so thought I'd ask for some help.

```
- (NSInteger)getNextSubjectId {

    DrillDownAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (DrillDownAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:appDelegate.getDBPath];    
    [database open];

    FMResultSet *rst = [database executeQuery:@"select max(subject_id) + 1 AS SUBJECT_ID from SUBJECT"];

    NSLog(@"PRINT FIRST SUBJECT_ID = %@", [rst stringForColumnIndex:0]);

    NSString *nextSubId = [rst stringForColumnIndex:0];
    [database close];

    NSLog(@"NEW SUBJECT_ID = %@", nextSubId);


    NSInteger myInt = [nextSubId intValue];

    return myInt;

    //    [maxSubjectId release];

}
```

The log shows:

2012-01-25 22:56:29.398 Quotes[6992:f803] PRINT FIRST SUBJECT_ID = (null)
(gdb)

The header looks like this:

```
//  Subject.h
//  DrillDownApp

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Subject : NSObject {
    NSInteger subject_id;
    NSString *category_title;
    NSString *title;
    BOOL isDirty;

}

- (id) initWithPrimaryKey:(NSInteger)pk;
- (void) addSubject;
- (NSInteger)getNextSubjectId;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL isDirty;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger subject_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * category_title;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First call [rst next]

Also, are you sure your `subject_id` is a **string** and not an **int**?

And finally, have you seen if you can use `lastInsertRowID`?

I use like this:

```
int lastRow = [[self getDatabase]lastInsertRowId];
```

Comment: Thank you very much and that fixed it.  I knew it was something stupidly simple.  I had it as a NSString earlier due to problems with initialization but thats fixed now so it goes straight to NSInteger without having to convert it.  I am checking out how to use the lastInsertRowId now but my primary key field was not set up originally as an auto increment and not sure if this will work.

Comment: Glad you got it working. The simplest of oversights always trip us up.

Answer (score 1):

From the FMDB documentation:

> You must always invoke -[FMResultSet next] before attempting to access the values returned in a query, even if you're only expecting one.

Just call the **next** method on your **rst** before you call **stringForColumnIndex**.

Comment: Thanks for your help and this handled it!